# How to convert the returned XML to HTML?

Tags: html, asp.net, xml, web-services, http-post

I created a simple web service in ASP.net that does some operations:

```
[WebMethod]
public int Area(int l, int b)
    {
return l * b;
    }

[WebMethod]
public int Perimeter(int l, int b)
{
return 2 * (l +b);
}
```

and i called it in HTML file, like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>WebService Call using HTTP POST</title>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:56472/WebSite2/Service.asmx/Area" method="POST">
<input name="l">
<input name="b">
<input type="submit" value="Click for Area">
</form>
<form action="http://localhost:56472/WebSite2/Service.asmx/Perimeter" method="POST">
<input name="l">
<input name="b">
<input type="submit" value="Click for Perimeter">
</form>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

put this when i click for the result it will be returned as XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <int xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">30</int>
```

And what I want is i want the result in HTML not XML, how to do this?

Can someone help, please?

Thank You :)!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call the service via ajax call and use the response to populate the required tag in the HTML.
Check the code below, it's simple jQuery AJAX call,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:56472/WebSite2/Service.asmx/Area",
    method:"post",
    data: {
        l: "custom value",
        b: "custom value",
    }
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.length);
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
        var jXml = $(xmlDoc);
        var value = jXml.find("int").text();
        $("#result").text(value);
    },
    failure: function (err) {
        console.log("could not call the service : " + err);
    }
});
```

Couple of things to keep in mind

- Form submission will take you to next page and destroy Javascript context, that's why we need AJAX call which will just bring us the result from teh service without navigating away from the page.
- As server is returning data in XML you'll have to parse it either as XML document or as plain string to get the required values.

***Edited to add

Check out the complete example below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            <!-- create the function to call on click of a button -->
            function getData() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:56472/WebSite2/Service.asmx/Area",
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: "xml",
                    data: {
                        l: "custom value",
                        b: "custom value"
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("success " + data);
                        console.log(data.getElementsByTagName("int"));
                        var xmlDoc = data;
                        if(typeof(data) === "string") {
                            xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
                        }
                        var value = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("int")[0].textContent;

                        $("#result").text(value);
                   },
                   error: function(err) {
                      console.log("error " + JSON.stringify(arguments));
                   }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <!-- see the onclick attribute, you have to call your Javascript function in it's value -->
    <button onclick="getData();">click to get data</button>
    <!-- tag where it result will be displayed -->
    <h1 id="result">No result yet</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much for responding, sorry im not that good with ajax can you tell me how im gonna use this ajax with my html? plus can you recommend a link of how to parse returned xml please? thank you so much!

Comment: You can use this code as it is, I have used jQuery to parse XML but it can be done at the xmlDoc level, like using DOM functions like xmlDoc.getElementById or xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName. Insert this code in the <script> tag and call it on click of a button.
There's information on jQuery selectors here https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/, these selectors can be used on XML documents as well.

Comment: i know its stupid to ask this, but can you tell me how to call this ajax on button click ? it doesn't have a name or something so i can call it ?

Comment: I added a complete example, for your reference, simple answer is you can use "onclick" attribute of any DOM element to call a global Javascript function.

Comment: i tried to run the code, but nothing happened when i click on the button. in the l: "custom value", b: "custom value" , i should replace the custom value with number right?

Comment: Yes, also monitor the HTTP request logged by the ajax call in Network tab (Chrome > Settings>More tools>Developer tools, or simply press F12 on windows)

Comment: i got those errors: GET http://localhost:56472/WebSite2/Service.asmx/Area?l=4&b=3 500 (Internal Server Error)k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4n.extend.ajax @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4getData @ yyy.html:7onclick @ yyy.html:35
yyy.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:56472/WebSite2/Service.asmx/Area?l=4&b=3. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
yyy.html:27 error {"0":{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"},"1":"error","2":""}

Comment: Ok, origin null error means you're trying to open the page from the file system. Browsers disallow Ajax call from a file opened from file system. You'll have to put the page in the same server as the web service one. so that you can open your page with this kind of URL http://localhost:56472/your_html_page.html

Comment: should i write this html inside visual studio?